# Finding six-digit palindrome number. Works for four and five digits

Tags: ruby, palindrome

I have to find palindrome numbers which are Product of three-digit numbers. The program I made works for 2*2 and 3*2. But not for 3*3. Why? I can't figure out.

```
#initialized variables

x = 999             
y = 999


 while x > 100

    while y > 100

        num = x*y

        #Reversing the digits

        a = num/100000
        b = num%100000
        c = b/10000
        d = b%10000
        e = d/1000
        f = d%1000
        g = f/100
        h = f%100
        i = h/10
        j = h%10
        rev = 100000*j+10000*i+1000*g+100*e+10*c+a

        #Checking for palindrome

        if rev == num
            puts num
        end
        y -= 1

    end
    x -= 1  

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting `y` to 999 after each iteration of `x`, so your program isn't actually iterating over the full range of values as intended. Bump `y = 999` to just under `while x > 100`.

Comment: @Pr4njal please accept my answer if you feel I've addressed your issue, thanks!

Comment: This one line that I was missing... It frustrated me for two days... Thanks to u..

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code is pretty straightforward, except were you are reversing the digits.

I'd recommend two steps to solve this:

1. Extract the reverse portion into a separate function and write a bunch of unit tests to make sure it's doing what you think it is. My intuition is that it is not.
2. If that doesn't fix it, start writing tests for the whole thing. Actually, you should probably do that anyway.